# Python: copying a repeating dictionary into a list - last dict item being duped to all list items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Considering the following:

```
import re
sequence = 'FFFFFF{7}FFFFFF'
patterns = [ ('([0-9a-fA-F]+)', 'Sequence'),
    ('(\\([0-9a-fA-F]+\\|[0-9a-fA-F]+\\))', 'Option'),
    ('({[0-9a-fA-F]+})', 'Range'),
    ('(\\[[0-9a-fA-F]+:([0-9a-fA-F]+|\*)\\])', 'Slice'),
    ('(\\?\\?)+', 'Byte_value_Wildcard'),
    ('(\\*)+', 'Byte_length_wildcard') ]
fragment_counter = 0
fragment_dict= {}
fragments_list = []
while sequence:
    found = False
    for pattern, name in patterns:
        m = re.match (pattern,sequence)
        if m:
            fragment_counter+=1
            m = m.groups () [0]
            fragment_dict["index"]=fragment_counter
            fragment_dict["fragment_type"]=name
            fragment_dict["value"]=m
            print fragment_dict
            fragments_list.append(fragment_dict)
            sequence = sequence [len (m):]
            found = True
            break
     if not found: raise Exception ('Unrecognized sequence')

print fragments_list
```

Each time it hits the "print fragment_dict"line, I get the correct (expected) output:

```
{'index': 1, 'fragment_type': 'Sequence', 'value': 'FFFFFF'}
{'index': 2, 'fragment_type': 'Range', 'value': '{7}'}
{'index': 3, 'fragment_type': 'Sequence', 'value': 'FFFFFF'}
```

however, the list item  `fragments_list` is 3 copies of the final dict, not each of the lines as I expect:

```
[{'index': 3, 'fragment_type': 'Sequence', 'value': 'FFFFFF'}, {'index': 3, 'fragment_type': 'Sequence', 'value': 'FFFFFF'}, {'index': 3, 'fragment_type': 'Sequence', 'value': 'FFFFFF'}]
```

I am assuming this is because the `append` is referencing the instance of the dict, not copying each iteration of the dict. I looked at using the `list()` function, but on the dict item it just gives me a list of the dict keys.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm not wedded to data type, I just needed a way to hold 3 data elements (and maybe a 4th) for each fragment I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that you are actually using the code of my answer to your last question. I am always happy when my answers do actually help.

Taking into consideration, that in your previous question you stated that this parsing was only the warm-up for afterwards processing the parsed tokens, you might consider this:

Create a class for each token type you have. Implement a `process` method inside each of those, that will sometime do the actual processing (instead of the wolfing, bearing, foxing and badgering I do in the below code).

Then parse a whole stream with the `Stream` class. You can iterate over the tokens via `Stream.tokens` and you can process all the tokens contained by calling `Stream.process`.

You put these classes in one python file, import it into your main code and you just need to create an instance of `Stream` to parse it and process it.

Something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import re

class Sequence:
    def __init__ (self, raw): self.__raw = raw
    def __str__ (self): return 'Sequence {}'.format (self.__raw)
    def process (self): print ('Wolfing sequence {}'.format (self.__raw) )

class Option:
    def __init__ (self, raw): self.__raw = raw
    def __str__ (self): return 'Option {}'.format (self.__raw)
    def process (self): print ('Foxing option {}'.format (self.__raw) )

class Range:
    def __init__ (self, raw): self.__raw = raw
    def __str__ (self): return 'Range {}'.format (self.__raw)
    def process (self): print ('Bearing range {}'.format (self.__raw) )

class Slice:
    def __init__ (self, raw): self.__raw = raw
    def __str__ (self): return 'Slice {}'.format (self.__raw)
    def process (self): print ('Badgering slice {}'.format (self.__raw) )


class Stream:
    patterns = [ ('([0-9a-fA-F]+)', Sequence),
        ('(\\([0-9a-fA-F]+\\|[0-9a-fA-F]+\\))', Option),
        ('({[0-9a-fA-F]+})', Range),
        ('(\\[[0-9a-fA-F]+:[0-9a-fA-F]+\\])', Slice) ]

    def __init__ (self, stream):
        self.__tokens = []
        while stream:
            found = False
            for pattern, cls in self.patterns:
                m = re.match (pattern, stream)
                if m:
                    m = m.groups () [0]
                    self.__tokens.append (cls (m) )
                    stream = stream [len (m):]
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found: raise Exception ('Unrecognized sequence')

    @property
    def tokens (self): return (token for token in self.__tokens)

    def process (self):
        for token in self.__tokens: token.process ()

stream = Stream ('524946(46|58){4}434452[22:33]367672736E')
print ('These are the tokens:')
for idx, token in enumerate (stream.tokens):
    print ('{} at position {}.'.format (token, idx) )

print ('\nNow let\'s process them all:')
stream.process ()
```

This yields:

```
These are the tokens:
Sequence 524946 at position 0.
Option (46|58) at position 1.
Range {4} at position 2.
Sequence 434452 at position 3.
Slice [22:33] at position 4.
Sequence 367672736E at position 5.

Now let's process them all:
Wolfing sequence 524946
Foxing option (46|58)
Bearing range {4}
Wolfing sequence 434452
Badgering slice [22:33]
Wolfing sequence 367672736E
```

Comment: Hey, this is awesome, thanks! My next brickwall is facing me, and I suspect that your revised method will help me to navigate the resultant data object appropriately. I will implement, and then see what I can do, but essentially the next task is to be able to extract fragment entities per sequence based on some logic - (e.g. which fragment entity has the largest `len()` and what is its index). I'm sure I'll be back asking questions shortly, but thank you again for your input, its very useful! both to solve the problem in hand and to see how problems are solved by experienced users!

Comment: Its probably very much against the way things are done around here, but I wanted to thank you again for your help. Having had some time to put it together, Your code is perfect, and so very easy to (1) see whats going on and (2) work with. Its performs EXACTLY as I visualised. I'm absurdly appreciative!

Comment: You are welcome and I am happy to help. I would also gladly peer-review your code, once you are all set. One can always learn a bit one from another. Unfortunately SO doesn't allow for private messages, but if you can leave an eMail address here, I will contact you, in case you would like this peer review.

Comment: Thats a very kind offer, thank you! I'm very grateful. you can reach me at jay.gattuso at dia dot govt dot nz. I do have a whole slew of questions around interacting with the data structure your code makes - would you prefer I ask them on SO or over email?

Comment: Up to you, on SO prolly more people can have an advantage of it, and you get more points of views. If it is something very specialised don't doubt contacting me tho. I just sent you a mail.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. Instead of the `list()` function, which generates a new `list` from any sequence (in this case, a `dict` as a sequence is a sequence of its keys), use the `dict()` function, which generates a new `dict` from any mapping.

Or, maybe more simply, just use the `copy` method.

Or, even more simply, just move the `fragment_dict= {}` into the loop, so you build up a new `dict` instead of continuing to reuse the same one.

Comment: So simple. Infact I should have just tested `dict`! Thank you. Appreciated.

Comment: @JayGattuso: This is the kind of thing that's obvious once you know it, but not so much before you do…